# Get IMU acceleration of a direction when tilted

Tags: filters, math, sensor

I have an IMU that is placed on the body. My goal is to calculate the position data of the vertical upward movement. Since the sensor is never perfectly aligned and will always have a little tilt, I was wondering how to still get the straight upward acceleration.
So I was thinking about a parallelogram of forces and using Pythagoras to calculate it:

[image]

Imagining that the square represents the tilted device and I want to get Fr, is it possible to simply calculate Fr = [image: 2] ? Or am I missing a piece in this consideration? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This would only work all motion is guaranteed to be vertical, which is unlikely to be the case.

Most accelerometers will give you the acceleration in 3 axes. Earth gravity shows up there, so you can determine orientation of the sensor fairly well by looking at the bias on each of the axes. Once you have the orientation, you can determine the acceleration along the vertical axes by a co-ordinate rotation.

If your IMU is fancy enough, it may be able to do this by itself. I suggest spending some quality time with the data sheet and specifically looking to "pitch and roll".

Comment: Would you explain what you mean by "This would only work all motion is guaranteed to be vertical"? 

I forgot to mention that my IMU is moving constantly, besides the vertical movement. I read about pitch and roll but figured that this method wouldn't work accurately when the IMU moving.

Comment: This is a nice answer but keep in mind that some sensors reside on boards that along with the digitization of the data (analogue interfaces do exist too) may also subtract (or attempt to do so) the gravity force/bias. As you've already mentioned, spending some time with the data sheet is the best way to find your way around.

Answer (score 0):

An IMU unit essentially consists of three perpendicular mass-spring systems, each reperesenting an axis of measurement. An IMU unit determines the acceleration through the deformation of its spring and newton's law of motion. Ideally speaking, your method would work, but in reality the gravity forces are acting on the spring, such the IMU measure the gravity effect and the Ideal acceleration, which we are looking for.

Assuming only planer rotation of the body you are working on, you would land with the following measurement:
\begin{equation}
\vec{a}_{meas}=\begin{bmatrix}a_x\\a_y\\a_z\end{bmatrix}+ \begin{bmatrix}\frac{g}{m}\cos(\varphi)\\ \frac{g}{m} \sin(\varphi)\\0\end{bmatrix}+\vec{N}
\end{equation}
where $\vec{N}$ is a random noise vector, $\varphi$ is the angle between the $x$ direction and the direction of $g$ (vertical to the ground) and $m$ the mass hinged to the spring.

The easy solution would be to use an additional encoder to real-time measure the angle $\varphi$, and compensate the gravitational effect, then use a low-pass filter to throw out the extra additional noise.

Or if you are working on a system, which you can mathematically describe, and determine its state model, then you can use a Kalman filter or a bayesian filter  generally. If your noise isn't gaussian or strongly gaussian, then automatically exclude the Kalman filter solution, and go to either particle filters or recursive gauss newton filter.

Of course, the problem would be more complex for spatial movement, but it would follow the same concept.